# Display Smooth 3D models in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, 3d

I've constructed a MeshGeometry3D mesh in WPF and it's looks 'edgy'.
How can I render is smooth like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: triangles' normals should be correctly set.

Unfortunately, the tutorial article is already out of date, but "normals" is the key term necessary to achieve this.